# Textarea input filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filter

I have a form where my customers leave their feedback. After the form is submitted I have a query that displays the comments/reviews to my website.

Is there a method to filter out gibberish reviews like "cakjcnsakncaklcn" and block them from showing on my main site?

Addition: Another thought would be not to allow people to submit their comments if they have spelling mistakes. Is there a js validation for that or something similar?

Comment: Are you asking if there's a method to programming an English language parser? Then no.

Comment: i guess that would be the correct way to put it...

Comment: you can do some basic stuff on the server like check how many spaces vs characters were submitted. Enforce a minimum length, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this being submitted to a server that you have control over? I'm no NLP expert and I suppose there's a complicated way of doing this, but I would just test every word that gets submitted against an english dictionary and reject if none of the words are matches.

If you can't intercept this on the server, you can try using http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/

Comment: Yes I full control of the server and database. Your idea kind of makes sense and the javascript spell check may work. good thinking...

Comment: another thought, what if I do not allow people to submit their comments if the word has spelling mistakes on. Is there a js validation for that?

Comment: Any kind of feedback will typically contain small typos and many of them might not be intentional. The big question that you might want to ask yourself is how much of difficulty you want to present to genuine users to leave their feedback. For e.g. if they are likely to be prompted repeatedly to correct all their spelling mistakes before submitting, they are likely to get frustrated. So you might want to balance out your requirement v/s usability.

Comment: well, I was thinking to let everyone write what ever they want and then read their comments from my db and decide if I want to display the comment or not